# Unable to start debugging on web server

Tags: .net

unable to start debugging on the web server the microsoft visual studio Remote Debugging Monitor (msvsmon.exe does not appear to be running on the remote computer this may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer please see help for assistance on configuring remote debugging

[image]

Comment: and... is it running on the remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

1) Right click on your project in VS2005 or VS2008 or VS2010.
2) Click on Properties
3) Click on Web tab
4) Under Servers, click on the radio button Use Visual Studio Development Server
5) Check Auto Assign Port radio button
6) Uncheck NTLM Authentication and Enable Edit and Continue